# AngularJS won't set scope variable with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

All I want is to set a scope `change` before opening the modal 
so I put `ng-click="change = false;mode = 'edit';"` in the edit button

The wrong scenario is when I click on edit the scope should be `false`
but if I change it to `true` by pressing the change button and then I close the modal and I click again on edit to open the modal again you can see that the scope is still true while it should be reset back to false

Any explanations ?

I made this exemple in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2i80JkCduZYXy2k3XFzq?p=preview) ,

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="mode = 'add'">Add</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="change = false;mode = 'edit';">Edit</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" ng-switch on="mode">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" ng-switch-when="add">Add</h4>
          <h4 class="modal-title" ng-switch-when="edit">Edit</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>{{mode}} </p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="change = false" ng-show="change">Change</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="change = true" ng-show="!change">Revert</button>
          <p>{{change}} </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because angular uses prototypal inheritance while creating non-isolated scope. Since `ng-repeat`/`ng-if`/`ng-if` these template directives creates prototypically inherited child scope while rendering transcluded DOM in it. Worth reading [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14049480/2435473). This kind of issue generally happens with primitive data types like `string`, `bool`, `number`, etc. General practice to solve this issue would be using `object`(reference type). Using reference type while defining models on angular scope called as `Dot Rule`.

In your scenario you could consider creating `$scope.model = {}` object which will eventually hold your all properties related to that entity. While using them on HTML use `model.change` & `model.edit`.

You could even use `controllerAs` syntax while defining your controller, it bound all the binding variables to `this`(context) instead of `$scope`.

[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NJQd73xrOwpvAHqjgokE?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and the working demo !  I have a lot to know about AngularJS

Comment: @SoltaniNeji Glad to help you, Thanks :)

Comment: sure it helped a lot